# PowerShell: SharePoint 2010 Get calendar recurrence events

Tags: powershell, calendar, events

How to get sharepoint calendar list recurrence events by using powershell script?
I want to update end date of that recurrence events after retrieving it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not store all the recuring items within the list as seperate items.
It only stores 1 item (start) and has a XML definition within the listitem that declares the recuring events.
Access the item with REST and you will see the XML (Include RecurrenceData).
This will describe the configuration of the item.